# Gulp - copy and rename a file

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm extremely new to Gulp.  I'm basically trying to watch for a modified JavaScript file, and then make a new copy of it with a new name.  (eventually there'll be some processing on it, but Rome wasn't built in a day).

My (naive) attempt is this:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {

    return gulp.watch('../**/**.js', function(obj){
        gulp.src(obj.path)
            .pipe(gulp.dest('foobar.js'));
    });

});
```

This takes the modified file and successfully copies it into a folder now called foobar.js.  Is there anything simple I can replace `gulp.dest('foobar.js')` with that will simply copy and rename the src file in place?

---

EDIT

By copy in place, I mean I want to take the modified file, and make a copy of it right **where it currently is** with a new name.  The equivalent of clicking the file (in windows) and hitting control-c control-v, then renaming the resulting file.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain what you mean by

> copy and rename ... in place

But, based on your current code, if you simply wish to:

1. Watch all `.js` files in the **parent** directory and
2. Copy them to the `cwd` (current working directory) and
3. Name **all** copies, *regardless* of source file, the **same thing**

Then you could use [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) to do just that:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.watch('../**/**.js', function(obj) {
    gulp.src(obj.path)
      .pipe(rename('newFileName.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
  });
});
```

In this case, the output filename is `newFileName.js`

In order to use the module, you'll need to install the `gulp-rename` package with npm (ie: `npm install gulp-rename`).

More examples are available on the package details page on npm @ https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename#usage

Comment: +1 - thank you very much.  I apologize for the unclear question.  I threw an edit on my question to hopefully clarify.

Comment: @AdamRackis, using your updated code, I am unable to reproduce the issue. Are you **100%** positive that the change isn't happening in the copied file instead of the source file? If you `console.log(obj.path)` before your `gulp.src` line, can you verify that it is the **source file** that is triggering the watch task callback?

Comment: Ah - thinking about it the file change is overwriting the previous modified file which is triggering a new file.  Thanks so much for the help.  I'll get you some more upvotes :)

Comment: Nice to see that after 2 years on this site you finally found a question to answer!  Thanks again :)

Comment: Is there no way to do that without installing a new package?

Answer (score 14):

It wasn't pretty getting there, but in the end it appears this is what I want (with some ES6 transpiling in the middle).

The key appears to be the options object with a base property in the call to `src`.  That seems to be what's needed to maintain the path of the current file in the call to `dest`.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.watch('../**/$**.js', function(obj){
        if (obj.type === 'changed') {
            gulp.src(obj.path, { base: './' })
                .pipe(babel())
                .pipe(rename(function (path) {
                    path.basename = path.basename.replace('$', '');
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(''));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

20 lines of code to do 'cp file1 file2'

That's elegance.